# How to fix "near ")": syntax error" in sqlite

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I am working with Python and SQLite. I am constantly getting this message

> "near ")": syntax error".

I tried to add a semi-colon to all the queries but still, I get this error message.

```py
tables.append("""
                        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS payment (
                            p_id integer PRIMARY KEY,
                            o_id integer NON NULL,
                            FOREIGN KEY(o_id) REFERENCES orders(o_id),
                        );"""
                        )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a comma before the final closing **)**. Simply remove it.

i.e. use :-

```
tables.append("""
                        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS payment (
                            p_id integer PRIMARY KEY,
                            o_id integer NON NULL,
                            FOREIGN KEY(o_id) REFERENCES orders(o_id)
                        );"""
                        )
```

Comment: I figured it out. I was about to answer it myself by you guys did it first.

Answer (score 4):

Remove the comma in the end of the `FOREIGN KEY(o_id) REFERENCES orders(o_id),`

The working code will be:

```
tables.append("""
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS payment (
        p_id integer PRIMARY KEY,
        o_id integer NON NULL,
        FOREIGN KEY(o_id) REFERENCES orders(o_id)
    );"""
)
```

Comment: I figured it out. I was about to answer it myself by you guys did it first.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
tables = []
tables.append("""
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS payment p_id integer PRIMARY KEY,
o_id integer NON NULL FOREIGN KEY(o_id) REFERENCES orders(o_id),
              """)                                
print(tables)
```

Comment: There was a , after the last statement. Removing it fixed the bug.